How to Cancel a Specific Azure Function Instance on Demand?
I have a workflow consisting of multiple tasks, where each task is executed by an Azure Function. The functions are triggered by messages in a message bus.
E.g.:
Here is example source code of my azure function:
[Function(nameof(ProcessActivityRequest))]
    public async Task ProcessActivityRequest(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("QueueNameServicesBus", 
            Connection = "ServiceBus:ConnectionString")] ServiceBusReceivedMessage receivedMessage, FunctionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var invocationId = context.InvocationId;
            await AcitivityManager.Process(receivedMessage)
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           _logger.LogError(e, e.Message);
        }
    }

When a user cancels the workflow, I want to ensure that all associated Azure Function instances are also cancelled. For example, consider a scenario where I have one Azure Function named ProcessActivityRequest:

When Workflow A starts, it initiates one instance of ProcessActivityRequest (let's call it "Process 1").
When Workflow B starts, it triggers two more instances of ProcessActivityRequest (named "Process 2" and "Process 3").
If the user cancels Workflow B, I need to cancel "Process 2" and "Process 3" if they haven't completed yet, while "Process 1" should continue running without interruption.

I've researched this, and it seems like there is no straightforward way to cancel running process of an Azure Function triggered by Service Bus, other than shutting down the Azure Function host, as noted in this discussion.
Has anyone else faced this issue? If so, did you find a workaround to address it?
Edit:
Example of workflow with 4 tasks (using Elsa Workflow)

Cancel workflow:


Please share your complete function code

Can you clarify the meaning of workflow here and how are you cancelling the workflow?

Hi there,
A workflow, in this context, is a predefined series of tasks that need to be executed sequentially.
The user has two options: a button to start the workflow and another to cancel it. When the workflow starts, it sends a list of messages to a message bus queue, with each message triggering an instance of an Azure Function.
If the user decides to cancel the workflow, it’s necessary to terminate all associated Azure Function instances that have not been completed yet.

Can you share some screenshots of your workflow

Hi @IkhtesamAfrin, I already push some screenshots of the workflow in the edit part.

Can you explain more about what the use-case is? This is important because the method of cancellation might be different. For example, you might allow Process 2 to continue, but then make a final check at the end of some kind of cancellation flag, and then prevent committing the final change. This is quite different from having to actually terminate the whole process. I can give a suggested answer, but knowing more first would help.

Hi @AndrewB
The use-case here involves migrating data from another database, and I need to perform a final check at the end of Process 2 to either prevent the commit or take compensating actions if needed. It would be great if you could suggest some options for using a cancellation token effectively in this scenario.
Additionally, I would appreciate any advice on forcefully stopping the Azure Function process. Thank you!

I guess you need to think differently about how to structure an application for Cloud. Everything is distributed, so a concept of guaranteed consistency doesn't really work. There will always be a race condition, e.g. Process A sends the cancellation signal, believing Process B hasn't yet finished... But by the time the signal gets there, Process B has finished. In that respect, you may as well assume that Process B will always run to completion, and then run the compensating action if it turns out Process A had requested a cancellation. Happy to write an answer, but still need more info.

Hi @AndrewB, I really appreciate your answer! I can handle compensating actions directly within Process A, but since the migration process can take several hours, I need a way to cancel it if necessary. One workaround I've considered is creating a variable name IsCancellationRequest, stored in cache. Process B would periodically check the state of this variable, and if it changes to true, I can cancel Process B safely but this introduces performance overhead and isn’t the clean solution.
I’d love to hear your thoughts on this approach or any other recommendations you might have.

Unfortunately you can't share your IsCancellationRequest variable (or any cache) between Functions. This makes sense when you realise each Activity is run as a completely separate application instance - possibly even on a different server in Azure, even. Another challenge is I'm assuming you are using a SQL Transaction block around the migration process? If so, this means you can't "pause" the transaction while you return back to (say) a Durable Function. Can you give a really cut-down code sample so we can help further? For example, my assumption about the SQL transaction - is that right?

An idea could be to slightly refactor your code to use durable functions instead. You'd start the orchestrator when the user starts the workflow, start all the child instances from the orchestrator and, if needed, cancel the workflow by terminating all the child instances.

I don't think this will work. The termination only applies to the Orchestration; so any Activities that have been started (i.e. the Process A and Process B) will continue to run regardless. Actually this is made clear in the page you linked, where it says: Instance termination doesn't currently propagate. Activity functions and sub-orchestrations run to completion, regardless of whether you've terminated the orchestration instance that called them.
